# how to rewrite index.php?a=1 as a/1 in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

how to write rule for 
http://www.laji.com/index.php?a=1
can be visited as http://www.laji.com/a/1

I had add 127.0.0.1 www.laji.com to hosts.etc and set some in httpd.conf
http://www.laji.com/ == 'd:\phpnow\htdocs\laji'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(/)?([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/)?$ index.php?$2=$3
```

Each parentheses in the regexp can be used with the `$N` backreference, where N is the number of the parentheses counted from the left, as in matching-regexps.

Additionally you can be more strict in the brackets - to only accept letters in the first and numbers in the second argument -, or do this kind of validation in `index.php`